# BottomNavigationVIew: Glitch that overwrites other layout

Tags: java, android

I am using `BottomNavigationView` and I added `ListView` to my layout. After adding this `ListView`, the previous screen wont disappear and this new screen overwrites the previous screen. Does someone have an idea why this happens.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class favaoritesFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorites,container,false);

        String[] line =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.JR_East);
        ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,line);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

[The issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCpBS.png)

```
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listview"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show layout xml and how you are performing screen transactions. Maybe it is related to styles too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Adding android:background="@android:color/white" the glitch fixed.

Comment: Vote + will more appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Background in your parent View of all fragment,

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```